# Multiple Apps with One Apple Developer Account

Tags: iphone, app-store, account

If I already have one application in the Apple Store, can I test and publish another app using the same developer account? This may be a duplicate question but I haven't found a reliable answer so far, so please answer or direct me to the right answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes; this is handled through iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thank you! I will do more research and figure it out!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too basic, answered by Apple's own developer resources, and does not describe a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Actually I don't remember ever reading anything about any restrictions on how many apps you can sell/publish under one developer account. As long as you follow Apple's guidelines you should have no problems.

Comment: You may consider posting this as a comment.